# Documentation for Gallery3 Validation Rules

Tags: php, validation, gallery, kohana

I'm needing to change some of the rules used for form validation in the Gallery3 module "register".  However, I have no idea what validation system it's using or what I can do to modify it.  Can anyone tell me where I can find documentation for this?

Here's an example:

```
$group->input("email")->label(t("Email"))->id("g-email")
      ->rules("required|valid_email|length[1,255]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems [Gallery3 is built on Kohana 2.3](http://codex.gallery2.org/Gallery3%3aDeveloper_Handbook%3aFramework), and hitting their ORM docs reveals a section about validation:

http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/orm/validation

This seems like a good place to start. The actual API for the Validation class can be found here:

http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Validation

Digging a little deeper, the non-standard rules seem to be defined in each model in Gallery3:

https://github.com/gallery/gallery3/blob/master/modules/user/models/user.php

In the above model (extending ORM) there is a $rules property, and methods matching them prefixed with 'valid_' (eg. 'email' in the $rules property maps to the valid_email method)